# How to set the canvas location of a controltemplate element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to automatically set the canvas location of a controltemplate element.

The main element is positioned correctly on the canvas.

I want to set the top &left position of a textbox on a connector to be the midpoint of that connector. the connector is a path. The connector is on a canvas (i.e. the direct child of canvas), this scenario would be a label on an arrow, like would be seen in a flowchart. I have the following control template for the connector

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type vm:targettypehere}">
            <Grid Margin="0">                            
                <Path Data="{Binding MyPath.Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="ConnectorNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding ConnectorName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The path displays as expected and I am happy with it.
I want to place the textblock to the midpoint of the path.
I find the midpoint of the start and end points of the path like so

```
public void PlaceTextBlock()
{
    double xDist = (EndPoint.X - StartPoint.X);
    double yDist = (EndPoint.Y - StartPoint.Y);

    Point midPoint = new Point(StartPoint.X + xDist / 2, StartPoint.Y + yDist / 2);           

    //setting the textblock location
    var tpl = this.Template;
    var ctrl = (TextBlock)tpl.FindName("ConnectorNameTextBlock", this);

    Canvas.SetLeft(ctrl, midPoint.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(ctrl, midPoint.Y);

}
```

The code is finding the ctrl element and I can verify this in breakmode by seeing the string to display.
However the textblock always appears at (0,0) topleft of the canvas.

the connector is an A*path so it can be anything  not just a straight line.
the connector is the direct child of the canvas.

How can I set the top and left of an element in a controltemplate?
is there any other way other than setting margin?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to replace the Grid inside the ControlTemplate by a Canvas.